# Ocelot not working with .NET 6 running on docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, ocelot

I'm trying to configure Ocelot but i'm getting a 404.
Here's my Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration(app => app.AddJsonFile("configuration.json"));

builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Ocelot",
        Version = "v1",
        Description = "Ocelot."
    });
});
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger()
    .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Ocelot");
    });
app.UseOcelot().Wait();

app.Run();
```

My configuration.json:

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "api/v1/Catalog/items/{id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "catalog.api",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/v1/c/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST", "PUT", "GET" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": { "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5202" }
}
```

The request https://localhost:5202/v1/c/1 returns a 404.

The host catalog.api is my catalog microservice running on another docker container and its working, i've tested calling by its own port:
http://localhost:5101/api/v1/Catalog/items/1

Comment: Port is configured to 80 instead of 5101

Comment: Yes, 80 is the container port. 5101 is the host port.

Comment: what is the catalog.api ? is this the service name?

Comment: catalog.api is the catalog microservice container name. Same name defined in docker-compose

Comment: Starting v16 it's a `Routes` instead of `ReRoutes`

Comment: You're right, Artur. It works. Thanks.